# Logstash multiline codec in udp plugin is throwing error

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to work on logstash ingestion that is generating multiline syslog data. Example:

Event ID: 1234

Message: ABCD

Severity: High

I need to get the final output of log as Event ID: 1234 Message: ABCD Severity: High.

I tried using UDP input plugin with multiline codec and threw error as below :

`` [FATAL][logstash.runner ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<pipeline-blah>, :backtrace=> ["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in `add'", "/opt/blah/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in `block in converge_state'"]} ``

`Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:pipeline-blah, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ConfigurationError) Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:100)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:60)",......`

I am using below mentioned input config

```
    id => "pipeline_syslog_generic_input_udp"
    port => 5514
    codec => multiline {
    pattern => "^Event ID"
    what => "next" } // Also tried changing this to previous
    add_field => {
      "type" => "generic"
      "ingest_port" => "udp/5514"
    }
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if there is a better way to deal with this.

Comment: Can you add your complete pipeline please

Comment: @karanshah there is no filter and output is pointing to a common pipeline